# Setting dajax cache false

Tags: android, django, dajaxice, dajax

I'm using django v.1.6 and dajaxice v.0.6. I've run into a problem with ajax not functioning on some android devices running Chrome.

From what I understand, this is a caching problem. People using ajax on it's own seem to be getting round the problem by setting the cache to false within the ajax function. An example from [here](http://www.grobmeier.de/android-does-not-fire-ajax-reqests-because-they-are-caches-ajax-requests-at-least-on-jquery-mobile-10072011.html) shows how you might normally go about this with ajax.

```
$.ajax({
       url: "yoururl.html",
          context: document.body,
          cache : false,
          data: {
               username :  $('#username').val(),
               password :  $('#password').val(),
          },
          success: function ( data ) {
              // do something
         }
   });
```

And apparently that doesn't always work as in a reply to the previous code segment, someone has responded that after jQuery 1.7.1 you may need to add a timestamp like so:

```
$.ajax( { url: "someserver/somepath/blah" + "?_=" + jQuery.now(), type: "PUT", data: somedata});
```

Here is an example of the code I'm trying to get to work:

```
function refresh_word(){
  Dajaxice.game.refreshWord(Dajax.process,{'game_id':{{game.id}},'player_id':{{player.id}}});
}
```

Like I said, this works on iPhones and desktop browsers but fails on some android devices.

I'm clutching at straws, I tried disabling the cache for the entire page but it still doesn't seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

Is there a way to do this with dajax?

Thanks in advance for any help!